# New Lenovo X1 Carbon 2nd Generation - function key bar and vertical scrolling

Tags: hardware, lenovo

I just installed ubuntu 13.10 on a new x1 Carbon (second generation) and everything works fine so far. I adjusted the touchpad to disable "tap-to-click" and enabled "middle-mouse-button" and just fine tuning the touchpad (it is really bad in the default setup).

Now I have two problems left:

1. How can I make use of the function key bar? I can use F1-F12 just fine, but with "Fn" you should switch the OLEd to other keys. This does not work. Brightness/Settings/WLAN key does not work either.
2. How can I enable vertical scrolling with trackpoint and middle mouse button. On my lenovo T530 it worked out of the box.

Comment: This generation features the same non-physical buttons as the T440 models. Please have a look at [Trackpoint and Clickpad: enable buttons and scroll (Lenovo T440s)](http://askubuntu.com/q/380825/40581) regarding these buttons. There is a workaround while full support is being implemented.

Comment: I haven’t seen a workaround there (just for archlinux) but thank your for your comment.

Comment: Kernel version 3.15 will have a support for the adaptive keyboard. 3.15 rc4 [1] gives me a black screen. Still waiting for the working version. [1] http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.15-rc4-utopic/

Comment: Regarding your question: _How can I make use of the function key bar?_  take a look at [Installing GNU/Linux on a 2014 Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon](http://mako.cc/copyrighteous/installing-gnulinux-on-an-2014-lenovo-thinkpad-x1-carbon#fixing-the-adaptive-keyboard) under the heading called _Fixing the Adaptive Keyboard_.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a work around by enabling the proposed updates in "Software Sources", otherwise known as "Software and Updates" in Lubuntu 14.04

Check this out; this issue has been fixed if you can't wait for the 3.15 kernel to release

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1309609

Got it working only on the 3.13.9-27 kernel. Tried 3.14 with adaptive keyboard cycling as it should but not returning after resume from suspend.